# Programmatically activate Outlook

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, outlook, outlook-2010

I have an application which needs to activate Outlook (if it is running) when the user clicks on a button. I have tried the following but it isn't working.

Declared in the window class:

```
[DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow( IntPtr hWnd );
[DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
private static extern bool ShowWindowAsync( IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow );
[DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
private static extern bool IsIconic( IntPtr hWnd );
```

Within the button `Click` handler:

```
// Check if Outlook is running
var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName( "OUTLOOK" );

if( procs.Length > 0 ) {
  // IntPtr hWnd = procs[0].MainWindowHandle; // Always returns zero
  IntPtr hWnd = procs[0].Handle;

  if( hWnd != IntPtr.Zero ) {
    if( IsIconic( hWnd ) ) {
      ShowWindowAsync( hWnd, SW_RESTORE );

    }
    SetForegroundWindow( hWnd );

  }
}
```

This doesn't work irrespective of whether Outlook is currently minimized to taskbar or minimized to system tray or maximized. How do I activate the Outlook window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out a solution; instead of using any WINAPI calls I simply used `Process.Start()`. I'd tried this earlier too but it caused the existing Outlook window to resize, which was annoying. The secret is to pass the `/recycle` argument to Outlook, this instructs it to reuse the existing window. The call looks like this:

```
Process.Start( "OUTLOOK.exe", "/recycle" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not try spawning Outlook as a new process?  I believe it is a single-entry application (I'm forgetting my proper terminology here), so that if it is already open, it will just bring that one to forefront.

Comment: I tried that and it does wake up the currently running instance of Outlook, however, the window gets resized, so it is annoying to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This works (you might have to change the path):

```
public static void StartOutlookIfNotRunning()
{
    string OutlookFilepath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE";
    if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0) return;
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(OutlookFilepath);
    process.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen SetForegroundWindow fail on occasion. Try using the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545) function

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. I tried `SetWindowPos( hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 500, 500, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE )`. The return values for both `SetForegroundWindow` and `SetWindowPos` indicate success, and `IsIconic` is always returning false, even when Outlook is minimized. I'm beginning to think this is some quirk with Outlook 2010.

Comment: Ouch... Strange behavior. As a potential workaround, instead of focusing Outlook directly, maybe try launching the user's default email application? (Assuming Outlook is their default...)

Comment: The easiest way is: Process.Start("mailto:address@example.com");
That will invoke the handler for the 'mailto:' protocol, which is the default email client.